# focus in textbox after text asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to focus in textbox after text in asp.net c# but I am unable to do it

my c# code is given below, please tell me where i am wrong:-

```
 TextBox txtindex = (TextBox)RptTask.Items[Nextindex].FindControl("TxtDuration");
 txtindex.Focus();
```

Comment: What event are you doing this in? I would actually recommend applying this focus in JavaScript rather than in C#. Also, you might consider setting the `defaultfocus` attribute of the `form` itself to `TxtDuration`.

Comment: Take a look at the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). Make sure nothing is happening in any events after the event handling that might change the focus after your post back.

Comment: After TextDurationChanged event i am getting it coz i am trying after postback the page

Comment: Can anybody can solve this problem,please provide me solution for it!

Answer (score 1):

Apply Focus Method on Text in `Page_PreRender`

```
//pre-render code as given below, 
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
     {
       TextBox txtindex = (TextBox)RptTask.Items[Nextindex].FindControl("TxtDuration");
       txtindex.Focus();
     }
   catch(Exception ee)
    {
    }
}
```

Hope It will Help!

Comment: after prerender my page firing calendar prerender and dayrender events ,is this an issue of not focusing after text????